# Funcão do moodle mod_quiz_get_attempt_data retornando html incompleto

Tags: javascript, html, web-service, moodle

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação para o moodle que retorna o quiz em html. Fiz o uso do webservice `mod_quiz_get_attempt_data` mas o problema é que sempre que eu mando o request, o navegador retorna:

```
Uncaught TypeError: require is not a function
Uncaught ReferenceError: M is not defined
Uncaught ReferenceError: Y is not defined
```

Eu achei somente [um link](https://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=361913) em toda a internet que era para supostamente resolver meu problema, mas não funcionou. Como devo prosseguir para resolver isso? Eu estou fazendo algo errado?

Abaixo está a resposta JSON que recebo quando faço o request para o webservices:

```
{
  "attempt": {
    "id": 1,
    "quiz": 1,
    "userid": 2,
    "attempt": 1,
    "uniqueid": 1,
    "layout": "1,2,0",
    "currentpage": 0,
    "preview": 1,
    "state": "inprogress",
    "timestart": 1515194367,
    "timefinish": 0,
    "timemodified": 1515194367,
    "timemodifiedoffline": 1515194367,
    "timecheckstate": null,
    "sumgrades": null
  },
  "messages": [

  ],
  "nextpage": -1,
  "questions": [
    {
      "slot": 1,
      "type": "multichoice",
      "page": 0,
      "html": "<div id=\"q1\" class=\"que multichoice deferredfeedback notyetanswered\"><div class=\"info\"><h3 class=\"no\">Question <span class=\"qno\">1<\/span><\/h3><div class=\"state\">Not yet answered<\/div><div class=\"grade\">Marked out of 1.00<\/div><div class=\"questionflag editable\" aria-atomic=\"true\" aria-relevant=\"text\" aria-live=\"assertive\"><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"q1:1_:flagged\" value=\"0\" \/><input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"q1:1_:flaggedcheckbox\" name=\"q1:1_:flagged\" value=\"1\" \/><input type=\"hidden\" value=\"qaid=1&amp;qubaid=1&amp;qid=1&amp;slot=1&amp;checksum=01b16b432969d727271ce46f60fbd868&amp;sesskey=X2xjmV3Svi&amp;newstate=\" class=\"questionflagpostdata\" \/><label id=\"q1:1_:flaggedlabel\" for=\"q1:1_:flaggedcheckbox\"><img src=\"http:\/\/192.168.0.22\/moodle\/theme\/image.php\/_s\/boost\/core\/1515096229\/i\/unflagged\" alt=\"Not flagged\" id=\"q1:1_:flaggedimg\" \/><\/label>\n<\/div><\/div><div class=\"content\"><div class=\"formulation clearfix\"><h4 class=\"accesshide\">Question text<\/h4><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"q1:1_:sequencecheck\" value=\"1\" \/><div class=\"qtext\"><p>Um membro pode ser considerado um \u00f3rg\u00e3o ou m\u00fasculo. Isso significa que pizza \u00e9 \u00f3timo para comer \u00e0 noite.<\/p><\/div><div class=\"ablock\"><div class=\"prompt\">Select one:<\/div><div class=\"answer\"><div class=\"r0\"><input type=\"radio\" name=\"q1:1_answer\" value=\"0\" id=\"q1:1_answer0\" \/><label for=\"q1:1_answer0\" class=\"m-l-1\"><span class=\"answernumber\">a. <\/span>P\u00e9<\/label> <\/div>\n<div class=\"r1\"><input type=\"radio\" name=\"q1:1_answer\" value=\"1\" id=\"q1:1_answer1\" \/><label for=\"q1:1_answer1\" class=\"m-l-1\"><span class=\"answernumber\">b. <\/span>Nenhuma das alternativas<\/label> <\/div>\n<div class=\"r0\"><input type=\"radio\" name=\"q1:1_answer\" value=\"2\" id=\"q1:1_answer2\" \/><label for=\"q1:1_answer2\" class=\"m-l-1\"><span class=\"answernumber\">c. <\/span>Bra\u00e7o<\/label> <\/div>\n<div class=\"r1\"><input type=\"radio\" name=\"q1:1_answer\" value=\"3\" id=\"q1:1_answer3\" \/><label for=\"q1:1_answer3\" class=\"m-l-1\"><span class=\"answernumber\">d. <\/span>Nariz<\/label> <\/div>\n<\/div><\/div><\/div><\/div><\/div><script type=\"text\/javascript\">\n\/\/<![CDATA[\nvar require = {\n    baseUrl : 'http:\/\/192.168.0.22\/moodle\/lib\/requirejs.php\/1515096229\/',\n    \/\/ We only support AMD modules with an explicit define() statement.\n    enforceDefine: true,\n    skipDataMain: true,\n    waitSeconds : 0,\n\n    paths: {\n        jquery: 'http:\/\/192.168.0.22\/moodle\/lib\/javascript.php\/1515096229\/lib\/jquery\/jquery-3.2.1.min',\n        jqueryui: 'http:\/\/192.168.0.22\/moodle\/lib\/javascript.php\/1515096229\/lib\/jquery\/ui-1.12.1\/jquery-ui.min',\n        jqueryprivate: 'http:\/\/192.168.0.22\/moodle\/lib\/javascript.php\/1515096229\/lib\/requirejs\/jquery-private'\n    },\n\n    \/\/ Custom jquery config map.\n    map: {\n      \/\/ '*' means all modules will get 'jqueryprivate'\n      \/\/ for their 'jquery' dependency.\n      '*': { jquery: 'jqueryprivate' },\n      \/\/ Stub module for 'process'. This is a workaround for a bug in MathJax (see MDL-60458).\n      '*': { process: 'core\/first' },\n\n      \/\/ 'jquery-private' wants the real jQuery module\n      \/\/ though. If this line was not here, there would\n      \/\/ be an unresolvable cyclic dependency.\n      jqueryprivate: { jquery: 'jquery' }\n    }\n};\n\n\/\/]]>\n<\/script>\n<script type=\"text\/javascript\" src=\"http:\/\/192.168.0.22\/moodle\/lib\/javascript.php\/1515096229\/lib\/requirejs\/require.min.js\"><\/script>\n<script type=\"text\/javascript\">\n\/\/<![CDATA[\nrequire(['core\/first'], function() {\n;\nrequire([\"media_videojs\/loader\"], function(loader) {\n    loader.setUp(function(videojs) {\n        videojs.options.flash.swf = \"http:\/\/192.168.0.22\/moodle\/media\/player\/videojs\/videojs\/video-js.swf\";\nvideojs.addLanguage(\"en\",{\n \"Audio Player\": \"Audio Player\",\n \"Video Player\": \"Video Player\",\n \"Play\": \"Play\",\n \"Pause\": \"Pause\",\n \"Replay\": \"Replay\",\n \"Current Time\": \"Current Time\",\n \"Duration Time\": \"Duration Time\",\n \"Remaining Time\": \"Remaining Time\",\n \"Stream Type\": \"Stream Type\",\n \"LIVE\": \"LIVE\",\n \"Loaded\": \"Loaded\",\n \"Progress\": \"Progress\",\n \"Progress Bar\": \"Progress Bar\",\n \"progress bar timing: currentTime={1} duration={2}\": \"{1} of {2}\",\n \"Fullscreen\": \"Fullscreen\",\n \"Non-Fullscreen\": \"Non-Fullscreen\",\n \"Mute\": \"Mute\",\n \"Unmute\": \"Unmute\",\n \"Playback Rate\": \"Playback Rate\",\n \"Subtitles\": \"Subtitles\",\n \"subtitles off\": \"subtitles off\",\n \"Captions\": \"Captions\",\n \"captions off\": \"captions off\",\n \"Chapters\": \"Chapters\",\n \"Descriptions\": \"Descriptions\",\n \"descriptions off\": \"descriptions off\",\n \"Audio Track\": \"Audio Track\",\n \"Volume Level\": \"Volume Level\",\n \"You aborted the media playback\": \"You aborted the media playback\",\n \"A network error caused the media download to fail part-way.\": \"A network error caused the media download to fail part-way.\",\n \"The media could not be loaded, either because the server or network failed or because the format is not supported.\": \"The media could not be loaded, either because the server or network failed or because the format is not supported.\",\n \"The media playback was aborted due to a corruption problem or because the media used features your browser did not support.\": \"The media playback was aborted due to a corruption problem or because the media used features your browser did not support.\",\n \"No compatible source was found for this media.\": \"No compatible source was found for this media.\",\n \"The media is encrypted and we do not have the keys to decrypt it.\": \"The media is encrypted and we do not have the keys to decrypt it.\",\n \"Play Video\": \"Play Video\",\n \"Close\": \"Close\",\n \"Close Modal Dialog\": \"Close Modal Dialog\",\n \"Modal Window\": \"Modal Window\",\n \"This is a modal window\": \"This is a modal window\",\n \"This modal can be closed by pressing the Escape key or activating the close button.\": \"This modal can be closed by pressing the Escape key or activating the close button.\",\n \", opens captions settings dialog\": \", opens captions settings dialog\",\n \", opens subtitles settings dialog\": \", opens subtitles settings dialog\",\n \", opens descriptions settings dialog\": \", opens descriptions settings dialog\",\n \", selected\": \", selected\",\n \"captions settings\": \"captions settings\",\n \"subtitles settings\": \"subititles settings\",\n \"descriptions settings\": \"descriptions settings\",\n \"Text\": \"Text\",\n \"White\": \"White\",\n \"Black\": \"Black\",\n \"Red\": \"Red\",\n \"Green\": \"Green\",\n \"Blue\": \"Blue\",\n \"Yellow\": \"Yellow\",\n \"Magenta\": \"Magenta\",\n \"Cyan\": \"Cyan\",\n \"Background\": \"Background\",\n \"Window\": \"Window\",\n \"Transparent\": \"Transparent\",\n \"Semi-Transparent\": \"Semi-Transparent\",\n \"Opaque\": \"Opaque\",\n \"Font Size\": \"Font Size\",\n \"Text Edge Style\": \"Text Edge Style\",\n \"None\": \"None\",\n \"Raised\": \"Raised\",\n \"Depressed\": \"Depressed\",\n \"Uniform\": \"Uniform\",\n \"Dropshadow\": \"Dropshadow\",\n \"Font Family\": \"Font Family\",\n \"Proportional Sans-Serif\": \"Proportional Sans-Serif\",\n \"Monospace Sans-Serif\": \"Monospace Sans-Serif\",\n \"Proportional Serif\": \"Proportional Serif\",\n \"Monospace Serif\": \"Monospace Serif\",\n \"Casual\": \"Casual\",\n \"Script\": \"Script\",\n \"Small Caps\": \"Small Caps\",\n \"Reset\": \"Reset\",\n \"restore all settings to the default values\": \"restore all settings to the default values\",\n \"Done\": \"Done\",\n \"Caption Settings Dialog\": \"Caption Settings Dialog\",\n \"Beginning of dialog window. Escape will cancel and close the window.\": \"Beginning of dialog window. Escape will cancel and close the window.\",\n \"End of dialog window.\": \"End of dialog window.\"\n});\n\n    });\n});;\nrequire([\"core\/log\"], function(amd) { amd.setConfig({\"level\":\"warn\"}); });\n});\n\/\/]]>\n<\/script>\n<script type=\"text\/javascript\">\n\/\/<![CDATA[\nM.str = {\"moodle\":{\"lastmodified\":\"Last modified\",\"name\":\"Name\",\"error\":\"Error\",\"info\":\"Information\",\"yes\":\"Yes\",\"no\":\"No\",\"confirm\":\"Confirm\",\"areyousure\":\"Are you sure?\",\"closebuttontitle\":\"Close\",\"unknownerror\":\"Unknown error\"},\"repository\":{\"type\":\"Type\",\"size\":\"Size\",\"invalidjson\":\"Invalid JSON string\",\"nofilesattached\":\"No files attached\",\"filepicker\":\"File picker\",\"logout\":\"Logout\",\"nofilesavailable\":\"No files available\",\"norepositoriesavailable\":\"Sorry, none of your current repositories can return files in the required format.\",\"fileexistsdialogheader\":\"File exists\",\"fileexistsdialog_editor\":\"A file with that name has already been attached to the text you are editing.\",\"fileexistsdialog_filemanager\":\"A file with that name has already been attached\",\"renameto\":\"Rename to \\\"{$a}\\\"\",\"referencesexist\":\"There are {$a} alias\\\/shortcut files that use this file as their source\",\"select\":\"Select\"},\"admin\":{\"confirmdeletecomments\":\"You are about to delete comments, are you sure?\"}};\n\/\/]]>\n<\/script>\n<script type=\"text\/javascript\">\n\/\/<![CDATA[\n(function() {Y.use(\"moodle-filter_mathjaxloader-loader\",function() {M.filter_mathjaxloader.configure({\"mathjaxconfig\":\"MathJax.Hub.Config({\\r\\n    config: [\\\"Accessible.js\\\", \\\"Safe.js\\\"],\\r\\n    errorSettings: { message: [\\\"!\\\"] },\\r\\n    skipStartupTypeset: true,\\r\\n    messageStyle: \\\"none\\\"\\r\\n});\\r\\n\",\"lang\":\"en\"});\n});\n M.util.js_pending('random5a50bd7112dd91'); Y.on('domready', function() { M.util.js_complete(\"init\");  M.util.js_complete('random5a50bd7112dd91'); });\n})();\n\/\/]]>\n<\/script>\n",
      "sequencecheck": 1,
      "lastactiontime": 1515194367,
      "hasautosavedstep": false,
      "flagged": false,
      "number": 1,
      "state": "todo",
      "status": "Not yet answered",
      "blockedbyprevious": false,
      "maxmark": 1
    },
    {
      "slot": 2,
      "type": "multichoice",
      "page": 0,
      "html": "<div id=\"q2\" class=\"que multichoice deferredfeedback notyetanswered\"><div class=\"info\"><h3 class=\"no\">Question <span class=\"qno\">2<\/span><\/h3><div class=\"state\">Not yet answered<\/div><div class=\"grade\">Marked out of 1.00<\/div><div class=\"questionflag editable\" aria-atomic=\"true\" aria-relevant=\"text\" aria-live=\"assertive\"><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"q1:2_:flagged\" value=\"0\" \/><input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"q1:2_:flaggedcheckbox\" name=\"q1:2_:flagged\" value=\"1\" \/><input type=\"hidden\" value=\"qaid=2&amp;qubaid=1&amp;qid=2&amp;slot=2&amp;checksum=2ea29ddb23c03fa239ba5a0f29fd7bc8&amp;sesskey=X2xjmV3Svi&amp;newstate=\" class=\"questionflagpostdata\" \/><label id=\"q1:2_:flaggedlabel\" for=\"q1:2_:flaggedcheckbox\"><img src=\"http:\/\/192.168.0.22\/moodle\/theme\/image.php\/_s\/boost\/core\/1515096229\/i\/unflagged\" alt=\"Not flagged\" id=\"q1:2_:flaggedimg\" \/><\/label>\n<\/div><\/div><div class=\"content\"><div class=\"formulation clearfix\"><h4 class=\"accesshide\">Question text<\/h4><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"q1:2_:sequencecheck\" value=\"1\" \/><div class=\"qtext\"><p>\u00c9 muito claro que existem momentos para fazer determinada coisa, por exemplo, se voc\u00ea trabalha das 8h as 16h, voc\u00ea precisa estar no trabalho \u00e0s 8h. Sabendo disso, em que momento devemos respirar?<\/p><\/div><div class=\"ablock\"><div class=\"prompt\">Select one:<\/div><div class=\"answer\"><div class=\"r0\"><input type=\"radio\" name=\"q1:2_answer\" value=\"0\" id=\"q1:2_answer0\" \/><label for=\"q1:2_answer0\" class=\"m-l-1\"><span class=\"answernumber\">a. <\/span>Devemos respirar somente duas vezes ao dia, pois em excesso faz mal<\/label> <\/div>\n<div class=\"r1\"><input type=\"radio\" name=\"q1:2_answer\" value=\"1\" id=\"q1:2_answer1\" \/><label for=\"q1:2_answer1\" class=\"m-l-1\"><span class=\"answernumber\">b. <\/span>Nenhuma das alternativas est\u00e1 correta<\/label> <\/div>\n<div class=\"r0\"><input type=\"radio\" name=\"q1:2_answer\" value=\"2\" id=\"q1:2_answer2\" \/><label for=\"q1:2_answer2\" class=\"m-l-1\"><span class=\"answernumber\">c. <\/span>Nunca devemos respirar, pois faz mal \u00e0 sa\u00fade<\/label> <\/div>\n<div class=\"r1\"><input type=\"radio\" name=\"q1:2_answer\" value=\"3\" id=\"q1:2_answer3\" \/><label for=\"q1:2_answer3\" class=\"m-l-1\"><span class=\"answernumber\">d. <\/span>Devemos respirar todo o tempo, caso contr\u00e1rio morremos<\/label> <\/div>\n<\/div><\/div><\/div><\/div><\/div><script type=\"text\/javascript\">\n\/\/<![CDATA[\nvar require = {\n    baseUrl : 'http:\/\/192.168.0.22\/moodle\/lib\/requirejs.php\/1515096229\/',\n    \/\/ We only support AMD modules with an explicit define() statement.\n    enforceDefine: true,\n    skipDataMain: true,\n    waitSeconds : 0,\n\n    paths: {\n        jquery: 'http:\/\/192.168.0.22\/moodle\/lib\/javascript.php\/1515096229\/lib\/jquery\/jquery-3.2.1.min',\n        jqueryui: 'http:\/\/192.168.0.22\/moodle\/lib\/javascript.php\/1515096229\/lib\/jquery\/ui-1.12.1\/jquery-ui.min',\n        jqueryprivate: 'http:\/\/192.168.0.22\/moodle\/lib\/javascript.php\/1515096229\/lib\/requirejs\/jquery-private'\n    },\n\n    \/\/ Custom jquery config map.\n    map: {\n      \/\/ '*' means all modules will get 'jqueryprivate'\n      \/\/ for their 'jquery' dependency.\n      '*': { jquery: 'jqueryprivate' },\n      \/\/ Stub module for 'process'. This is a workaround for a bug in MathJax (see MDL-60458).\n      '*': { process: 'core\/first' },\n\n      \/\/ 'jquery-private' wants the real jQuery module\n      \/\/ though. If this line was not here, there would\n      \/\/ be an unresolvable cyclic dependency.\n      jqueryprivate: { jquery: 'jquery' }\n    }\n};\n\n\/\/]]>\n<\/script>\n<script type=\"text\/javascript\" src=\"http:\/\/192.168.0.22\/moodle\/lib\/javascript.php\/1515096229\/lib\/requirejs\/require.min.js\"><\/script>\n<script type=\"text\/javascript\">\n\/\/<![CDATA[\nrequire(['core\/first'], function() {\n;\nrequire([\"media_videojs\/loader\"], function(loader) {\n    loader.setUp(function(videojs) {\n        videojs.options.flash.swf = \"http:\/\/192.168.0.22\/moodle\/media\/player\/videojs\/videojs\/video-js.swf\";\nvideojs.addLanguage(\"en\",{\n \"Audio Player\": \"Audio Player\",\n \"Video Player\": \"Video Player\",\n \"Play\": \"Play\",\n \"Pause\": \"Pause\",\n \"Replay\": \"Replay\",\n \"Current Time\": \"Current Time\",\n \"Duration Time\": \"Duration Time\",\n \"Remaining Time\": \"Remaining Time\",\n \"Stream Type\": \"Stream Type\",\n \"LIVE\": \"LIVE\",\n \"Loaded\": \"Loaded\",\n \"Progress\": \"Progress\",\n \"Progress Bar\": \"Progress Bar\",\n \"progress bar timing: currentTime={1} duration={2}\": \"{1} of {2}\",\n \"Fullscreen\": \"Fullscreen\",\n \"Non-Fullscreen\": \"Non-Fullscreen\",\n \"Mute\": \"Mute\",\n \"Unmute\": \"Unmute\",\n \"Playback Rate\": \"Playback Rate\",\n \"Subtitles\": \"Subtitles\",\n \"subtitles off\": \"subtitles off\",\n \"Captions\": \"Captions\",\n \"captions off\": \"captions off\",\n \"Chapters\": \"Chapters\",\n \"Descriptions\": \"Descriptions\",\n \"descriptions off\": \"descriptions off\",\n \"Audio Track\": \"Audio Track\",\n \"Volume Level\": \"Volume Level\",\n \"You aborted the media playback\": \"You aborted the media playback\",\n \"A network error caused the media download to fail part-way.\": \"A network error caused the media download to fail part-way.\",\n \"The media could not be loaded, either because the server or network failed or because the format is not supported.\": \"The media could not be loaded, either because the server or network failed or because the format is not supported.\",\n \"The media playback was aborted due to a corruption problem or because the media used features your browser did not support.\": \"The media playback was aborted due to a corruption problem or because the media used features your browser did not support.\",\n \"No compatible source was found for this media.\": \"No compatible source was found for this media.\",\n \"The media is encrypted and we do not have the keys to decrypt it.\": \"The media is encrypted and we do not have the keys to decrypt it.\",\n \"Play Video\": \"Play Video\",\n \"Close\": \"Close\",\n \"Close Modal Dialog\": \"Close Modal Dialog\",\n \"Modal Window\": \"Modal Window\",\n \"This is a modal window\": \"This is a modal window\",\n \"This modal can be closed by pressing the Escape key or activating the close button.\": \"This modal can be closed by pressing the Escape key or activating the close button.\",\n \", opens captions settings dialog\": \", opens captions settings dialog\",\n \", opens subtitles settings dialog\": \", opens subtitles settings dialog\",\n \", opens descriptions settings dialog\": \", opens descriptions settings dialog\",\n \", selected\": \", selected\",\n \"captions settings\": \"captions settings\",\n \"subtitles settings\": \"subititles settings\",\n \"descriptions settings\": \"descriptions settings\",\n \"Text\": \"Text\",\n \"White\": \"White\",\n \"Black\": \"Black\",\n \"Red\": \"Red\",\n \"Green\": \"Green\",\n \"Blue\": \"Blue\",\n \"Yellow\": \"Yellow\",\n \"Magenta\": \"Magenta\",\n \"Cyan\": \"Cyan\",\n \"Background\": \"Background\",\n \"Window\": \"Window\",\n \"Transparent\": \"Transparent\",\n \"Semi-Transparent\": \"Semi-Transparent\",\n \"Opaque\": \"Opaque\",\n \"Font Size\": \"Font Size\",\n \"Text Edge Style\": \"Text Edge Style\",\n \"None\": \"None\",\n \"Raised\": \"Raised\",\n \"Depressed\": \"Depressed\",\n \"Uniform\": \"Uniform\",\n \"Dropshadow\": \"Dropshadow\",\n \"Font Family\": \"Font Family\",\n \"Proportional Sans-Serif\": \"Proportional Sans-Serif\",\n \"Monospace Sans-Serif\": \"Monospace Sans-Serif\",\n \"Proportional Serif\": \"Proportional Serif\",\n \"Monospace Serif\": \"Monospace Serif\",\n \"Casual\": \"Casual\",\n \"Script\": \"Script\",\n \"Small Caps\": \"Small Caps\",\n \"Reset\": \"Reset\",\n \"restore all settings to the default values\": \"restore all settings to the default values\",\n \"Done\": \"Done\",\n \"Caption Settings Dialog\": \"Caption Settings Dialog\",\n \"Beginning of dialog window. Escape will cancel and close the window.\": \"Beginning of dialog window. Escape will cancel and close the window.\",\n \"End of dialog window.\": \"End of dialog window.\"\n});\n\n    });\n});;\nrequire([\"core\/log\"], function(amd) { amd.setConfig({\"level\":\"warn\"}); });;\nrequire([\"core\/log\"], function(amd) { amd.setConfig({\"level\":\"warn\"}); });\n});\n\/\/]]>\n<\/script>\n<script type=\"text\/javascript\">\n\/\/<![CDATA[\nM.str = {\"moodle\":{\"lastmodified\":\"Last modified\",\"name\":\"Name\",\"error\":\"Error\",\"info\":\"Information\",\"yes\":\"Yes\",\"no\":\"No\",\"confirm\":\"Confirm\",\"areyousure\":\"Are you sure?\",\"closebuttontitle\":\"Close\",\"unknownerror\":\"Unknown error\"},\"repository\":{\"type\":\"Type\",\"size\":\"Size\",\"invalidjson\":\"Invalid JSON string\",\"nofilesattached\":\"No files attached\",\"filepicker\":\"File picker\",\"logout\":\"Logout\",\"nofilesavailable\":\"No files available\",\"norepositoriesavailable\":\"Sorry, none of your current repositories can return files in the required format.\",\"fileexistsdialogheader\":\"File exists\",\"fileexistsdialog_editor\":\"A file with that name has already been attached to the text you are editing.\",\"fileexistsdialog_filemanager\":\"A file with that name has already been attached\",\"renameto\":\"Rename to \\\"{$a}\\\"\",\"referencesexist\":\"There are {$a} alias\\\/shortcut files that use this file as their source\",\"select\":\"Select\"},\"admin\":{\"confirmdeletecomments\":\"You are about to delete comments, are you sure?\"}};\n\/\/]]>\n<\/script>\n<script type=\"text\/javascript\">\n\/\/<![CDATA[\n(function() {Y.use(\"moodle-filter_mathjaxloader-loader\",function() {M.filter_mathjaxloader.configure({\"mathjaxconfig\":\"MathJax.Hub.Config({\\r\\n    config: [\\\"Accessible.js\\\", \\\"Safe.js\\\"],\\r\\n    errorSettings: { message: [\\\"!\\\"] },\\r\\n    skipStartupTypeset: true,\\r\\n    messageStyle: \\\"none\\\"\\r\\n});\\r\\n\",\"lang\":\"en\"});\n});\n M.util.js_pending('random5a50bd7112dd91'); Y.on('domready', function() { M.util.js_complete(\"init\");  M.util.js_complete('random5a50bd7112dd91'); });\n M.util.js_pending('random5a50bd7112dd92'); Y.on('domready', function() { M.util.js_complete(\"init\");  M.util.js_complete('random5a50bd7112dd92'); });\n})();\n\/\/]]>\n<\/script>\n",
      "sequencecheck": 1,
      "lastactiontime": 1515194367,
      "hasautosavedstep": false,
      "flagged": false,
      "number": 2,
      "state": "todo",
      "status": "Not yet answered",
      "blockedbyprevious": false,
      "maxmark": 1
    }
  ],
  "warnings": [

  ]
}
```

Abaixo está um screenshot do erro que aparece no console:
[image: Console.log]

Comment: Esse arquivo find.php, foi você que criou ou é do proprio moodle?

Comment: Foi eu quem criou msm

Comment: Da para colocar o conteudo das linhas que apresentam erro?

Comment: Olá amigo, o erro já foi anexado na pergunta